# How to implement Carousel View in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, carousel, xamarin.forms

Is there any way we can create Carousel View instead of Carousel page so that only portion of the page swipes left or right. Also I want to create this control in the Xamarin Forms and not specific to platform.

If we need to create this custom control in the xamarin.android or xamarin.iOS then what is the real benefits of using the Xamarin.forms where this simple requirements are not getting satisfied.

Comment: It's not really clear what do you want to know. Do you want something like horizontal slideshow? Do you want a carousel with 3D animation? Do you just want to know if Xamarin.Forms fits your needs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204807/when-to-use-xamarin-forms-vs-xamarin-native/32205163#32205163

Answer (score 5):

There's a well documented CarouselView project hosted on github:

https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview
and
http://chrisriesgo.com/xamarin-forms-carousel-view-recipe/

Comment: Would that work for Windows phone, UWP and Windows project types in the version of Xamarin that comes with VS 2015?

Answer (score 3):

The nuget package for the CarouselView is now available (v2.3.0-pre1):
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/2.3.0-pre1

Answer (score 2):

We can use the CarouselView which was introduced in Xamarin forms 4.3. Now in Xamarin 4.6, we don't have to use the `Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");` in appdelegate of iOS and mainactivity of android.

However, to use the **indicatorview** for the Carousel page we have to set this 
Forms.SetFlags("IndicatorView_Experimental"); in appdelegate of iOS and mainactivity of android.

Answer (score 1):

I have just implemented a similar thing. To create the a carousel view, I just created a horizontal Stacklayout, wrapped in a horizontal scroll view.

In my particular example, I needed to create an image gallery. I used the Camera control from the Xamarin.Labs project to get the image from either the camera roll or the camera itself. I then added this as a child to the Stacklayout.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As of `Xamarin.Forms V2.2.0-pre1` `CarouselView` has now been added to Xamarin.Forms.

> **CarouselView**
>
> CarouselView is intended to fully replace CarouselPage. CarouselPage
>   will be deprecated in a future release. CarouselView is superior in
>   many ways, including its ability to be virtualized and nested within
>   layouts.

See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63983/xamarin-forms-2-2-0-pre1-released#latest

Unfortunately there is no documentation on this as of yet.

**EDIT:**

`CarouselView` was Removed for `Xamarin.Forms V2.2.0.31` because it wasn't ready for stable release. But from the look of it it will be merged back soon.

For now you can find the seperate `CarouselView` nuget package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/2.3.0-pre1

and you can use it like so:

Namespace:

```
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
```

Then we can simply add the CarouselView at the top of our page:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height=".3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height=".7*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Zoos}" x:Name="CarouselZoos">
    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
          <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
  </cv:CarouselView>
  <!--List of Monkeys below-->
</Grid>
```

more info: https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

Comment: looks like CarouselView no longer exists. What happened?

Comment: CarouselView was Removed for `V2.2.0.31` because it wasn't ready for release. But from the look of it it will be merged back into the next stable release

Comment: does it mean that it is not safe to use this package?

Comment: @batmaci Pre-Release means use the package but be aware it will probably contain bugs and isnt ideal for applications that need to be released

Comment: @user1 Do you know how to implement PostionSelected event using mvvm?

Comment: @batmaci not sure off the top of my head, I would ask a stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1):

If you use Xamarin.Forms V2.2.0-pre1 and you need to display different views for each page, you can use a derived class like that:

```
public class CarouselViewMultiPage : CarouselView
{
    List<View> _children = new List<View> { };
    public List<View> Children {
        get { return _children; }
        set {
            _children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public CarouselViewMultiPage ()
    {
        this.ItemTemplate = new CarouselTemplateSelector();
        this.ItemsSource = Children;
        this.SetBinding(CarouselView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Children");
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class CarouselTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
        View civ = (View)item;
        return new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            return civ;
        });
    }
}
```

so you can call it passing Views:

```
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new ContentPage {
        Content = new CarouselViewMultiPage
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children =
                       {
                            new Label() { Text="Page 1"},
                            new Label() { Text="Page 2"},
                            new Label() { Text="Page 3"},
                        }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CarouselView has been introduced in Xamarin forms v4.4. You can have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/). In additional to `CarouselView`, `IndicatorView` is also added to indicate the nth item in the carousel.