# Convert .axml to .xaml

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am searching for more then 2 days and now I decided to ask here.

Is it possible to convert Android `axml` (the same as xml) template to `Xamarin.Form`'s xaml template.

I am not good with template. That way I need some transformer tool but I can not find it. Or a good docs how to do it or what to change.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6):

Even if you could find such tool, I'd advise you not to use it because there is no direct translation between what Android can do and what Xamarin.Forms can. Since Forms is meant to run on multiple platforms, it has a much smaller scope and hence not all Android Views have a Forms counterpart.

If your template is simple, translating it by hand wouldn't be hard. If your template is complex, a tool wouldn't translate it efficiently

Comment: thank your. So now is my question what is better? Xamarin forms or split to xamarin android and iOS. I am new with xaml.

Comment: @senzacionale I recently [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32205377/3465182) a question on this regard :)