# Is it Possible to Create Couple of Screens in Xamrin and then import them in iOS and Android projects?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

We have some complicated forms and were thinking to create them in Xamrin and then import them in my native iOS and Android project (to be consistent and save effort/time).

I was wondering if this is even possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the app for Android and iOS with Xamarin.Forms. Then you don't need to transfer any code from one platform to another.

It's not possible to *convert* an Android Activity to iOS. See this answer for more information: [Automatically convert code between Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191762/automatically-convert-code-between-xamarin-ios-and-xamarin-android/33191948#33191948)

When you build a native iOS app with Objective-C or Swift then you need to create the UI with the native XCode tooling.

Comment: thanks. Actually I don't want to create the whole app, just couple of screens and then import those 2 screens or binary in my XCdoe and Android Studio Project.