# Can I have a Xamarin.Forms project with PCLs and shared code?

Tags: c#, android, ios, azure, xamarin.ios

**UPDATE:** I realized where my confusion came from.

You can start a project with PCLs, then turn it into a shared project, but you cannot start with a shared project then add PCLs.

---

I understand the differences between PCL and Shared in Xamarin, as well as Xamarin native (iOS, Android) vs Shared. [There is a great comparison on it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204807/when-to-use-xamarin-forms-vs-xamarin-native/32205163#32205163)

What I am not sure of, is if I can use PCLs and shared code in the same project. For example, if I want to work on a project which require a plugin, such as *plugin.media,* how can I **also** use blob storage, with the Azure.Storage namespace, if that requires shared code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can reference both a PCL and a Shared Project (shproj) from the same project.