# Which File to be used to develop mobile app in VS. wether axml or xaml?

Tags: c#, android, xaml

i am new to xamarin.

I have started with Xamarin and done all the installation process. Everything is went well till now. But later for some information I was searching in net. Then I came to know that to build on multiple OS like android and ios I have to write in xaml files. But in demoes normal axml files they have used.
The link using axml is 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/

let me know in which I have to develop. Weather I have to use axml or xaml files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a cross platform solution go through this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_3_-_setting_up_a_xamarin_cross_platform_solution/

Answer (score 0):

So in Xamarin you have two ways to develop apps:

1-Platform specific, where you will have one code base for your business logic (like calling services, your  app logice ..etc).
and for every platform you will need to write a specific UI code (pages, axml is android, storybaords on ios, xaml on windows)

2-Xamarin forms, where you will have everything in one place, the business logic the UIs (Using only Xaml for ios/Android/Windows).

Now it sounds like Xamarin forms is a good solution (which is true) but if you need to access *some* platform specific feature or you want to add fine details to the UIs you might want to use the platform specific route

Checkout this discussion:
[When to use Xamarin.Forms vs Xamarin Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204807/when-to-use-xamarin-forms-vs-xamarin-native)