# What will be the nuget package output of Xamarin native and Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I had been developed one Android Application in Xamarin Native Android about a year ago. And it works fine. Now I want to create same application for iOS devices. So which one is better? Should I have to build new application in Xamarin Native iOS? Or should I go with Xamarin Forms?

The major thing is, I want to develop nuget package for this application. So I am using Xamarin Forms then only one nuget is generated or I have to generate two different nuget for different platform?
And if I am developing Xamarin Native iOS app then nuget package is different for both platforms i.e. One for Xamarin Native Android and One for Xamarin Native iOS. Right?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204807/when-to-use-xamarin-forms-vs-xamarin-native

Comment: But what about nuget package?

Comment: nuget packages are different for xamarin native and xamarin forms

Comment: @G.hakim, So If I am creating Native app then there will be tow nuget package, one for Android and second for iOS. Right? And if I am using Xamarin Forms then it will be just one for both platform. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Well it is supposed to be like that for most cases there might be places where you might have to either install it in all your projects or specifically on your forms portable project it varies from package to package